# Capitalisation of the l in the move to chat message

Tags: feature-request, chat

Is it possible to capitalise the l in the "let us continue this discussion in chat" message that appears in the comments when a specific chat room is created to avoid lengthy discussion in the comments?

**Added later:** I asked a [similar question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/597/capitalisation-of-possible-in-duplicate-comment) on the MathOverflow meta regarding the machine-generated duplicate comment.

Comment: I think that is something set by SE in the general case; I'm not sure it *can* be customized on a site-by-site basis.

Comment: @vermiculus: Then it should be corrected *globally*.

Comment: How about making it a proper sentence by also including a full stop?

Comment: I thought no one but me worried about this sort of thing.

Comment: I had thought that the improper grammar and punctuation is deliberate, so that the reader **knows** that the message was sent by a machine and not a human.

Comment: @WillieWong: Does it matter whether the message was sent by a human or a machine? Does it matter that whoever reads the message knows it was sent by a machine?

Comment: @WillieWong With the varied userbase here, would improper grammar not make it more likely to have been written by a human, rather than less?

Comment: Idk. U tell me, @Tobias!

Comment: related (and status-declined): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/capitalize-possible-in-the-automatically-inserted-comments-when-you-vote-to-cl

Comment: @Willie: You give too much credit to the average English level on the internets. :(

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese and others, I had thought that with such an outrageous comment (cf. Asaf's comment immediately prior), the readers **would know** that I was being facetious.

Comment: @Willie: Any text on the internet without a smiley at the end can be, and will be, taken seriously.